# An elementary bound on the prime counting function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, analytic-number-theory

I'm currently working on some Number Theory exercises and I've hit a roadblock with this particular one. I'm a bit doubtful about my proof because the provided solution differs from mine. Not only that but it appears that the argument below leads to a sharper inequality: > instead of $\geq$. I'm afraid that I might have overlooked something, and I would really appreciate some feedback.

> Show that $\pi(x) \geq \log \log x$, where $\pi(x)$ is the prime counting function.

**My attempt:** Let's begin by observing that the $k$-th prime, denoted as $p_k$, satisfies the inequality $p_k < 2^{2^{k}}$. Consequently, since $\log$ is strictly increasing, it follows that $\log \log p_k < k \log 2 + \log \log 2$. Expressing this in terms of the $\pi(x)$ function, $\log \log p < \pi(p) \log 2 + \log \log 2$ for any prime $p$.

Now, for an arbitrary $x \in \mathbb{N}$, define $p_0 = \operatorname{min}\{p\text{ prime};\ p > x\}$. This leads us to

\begin{align}
\log \log x < \log \log p_0 < \pi(p_0) \log 2 + \log \log 2.
\end{align}

Note that, by the definition of $p_0$, $\pi(x) + 1 = \pi(p_0)$. Then,
\begin{align}\log \log x &< (\pi (x) + 1) \log 2 + \log \log 2 
\\ &= \pi(x) \log 2 + \log 2 + \log \log 2
\\ &= \pi(x) +( - \pi(x)(1 - \log 2) + \log 2 + \log \log 2).
\end{align}
We know that, for $x \geq 3$, $\pi(x) \geq 2$. Therefore, the expression within the parentheses in the preceding inequality is negative for those values of $x$:
\begin{align}
-\pi(x) (1-\log 2)+\log 2 + \log \log 2 \leq -2(1-\log 2)+\log 2 + \log \log 2 \approx -0.28707.
\end{align}
Thus, $\log \log x < \pi(x)$ for every $x \geq 3$. Case $x = 2$ follows by direct verification.

Comment: The fact that a proof leads to $>$ in place of $\ge$ shouldn't be at all surprising, since this is a very weak lower bound. In my opinion, the assertion that $p_k < 2^{2^k}$ comes out of nowhere (and is more or less equivalent to the statement to be proved), while everything after that assertion is fine.

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks for your comment! I was a bit unsure at first, thinking I might have made a mistake. The statement $p_k < 2^{2^k}$ is from an earlier exercise in the book I'm currently reading, so I thought about using it, since, as you mentioned, both results seem pretty similar. It follows by a straightforward induction after noticing that $p_{k+1} \leq p_1 p_2 \ldots p_k + 1$.